# RichFaces 3.3 JSP 1.2 seam 2.2 width and height is 0 ( auto ) always?

Tags: height, width, richfaces

I need to learn richfaces 3.3 with jboss seam 2.2 and JSF 1.2
( very old project for company; at least 10 years )
I use JBoss Application Server 7.2.0.

I have a project called RichFDemo made with Eclipse Neon Dynamic Web Module 2.5.

My problem is:
when I inspect/debug in chrome the page the 
width and height is 0 or auto always !
Unbelievable !

I do not have errors at compiling or deploy !

I put
RichFDemo\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib

```
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-digester.jar
commons-logging.jar
dom4j.jar
gwt-servlet.jar
hibernate-validator.jar
jboss-el.jar
jboss-seam-debug.jar
jboss-seam-excel.jar
jboss-seam-gen.jar
jboss-seam-ioc.jar
jboss-seam-jul.jar
jboss-seam-mail.jar
jboss-seam-pdf.jar
jboss-seam-remoting.jar
jboss-seam-resteasy.jar
jboss-seam-ui.jar
jboss-seam.jar
jhighlight-1.0.jar
jsf-api.jar
jsf-facelets.jar
jsf-impl.jar
jsp-api.jar
jstl-api-1.2.jar
jstl-impl-1.2.jar
jta.jar
junit-4.12.jar
log4j.jar
nekohtml.jar
richfaces-api.jar
richfaces-impl.jar
richfaces-ui.jar
servlet-api.jar
slf4j-api.jar
slf4j-log4j12.jar
xercesImpl.jar
```

### Here the version of jars is not clear displayed.

The web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    RichFDemo

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>
    <param-value>enable</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>  <!-- JSF needs to be initialized before Seam: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBSEAM-4401 -->

<!-- Seam -->

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>


<filter>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
            <param-name>createTempFiles</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value> <!-- note: if this is changed to true, all current uploads need to be changed too (item.getData()) -->
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>maxRequestSize</param-name>
            <param-value>419430400</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/seam/resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Document Store Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.seam.document.DocumentStoreServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Document Store Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.pdf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  

<!-- Facelets development mode (disable in production) -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.RESOURCE_RESOLVER</param-name>
    <param-value>at.paradine.jsf.resourceLoader.ClasspathAwareResourceLoader</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
    <param-value>500000</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Richfaces  -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
    <param-value>blueSky</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>NONE</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>NONE</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.RESOURCE_URI_PREFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>rfRes</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.COMPRESS_SCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- JSF -->

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
    <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.application.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>9000</session-timeout> 
</session-config> 

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error.jsp</location>
</error-page>


<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

---

faces-config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com    
/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
 version="1.2"> 

  <application>
  <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>    
  </application>

</faces-config>
```

---

And the test page

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />                   

<a:loadScript src="resource:////org/ajax4jsf/framework.pack.js"     
type="text/javascript" />
<a:loadScript src="resource:////org/richfaces/ui.pack.js"   
type="text/javascript" />
<a:loadScript src="/js/jQuery.splitter.js?rand=#  
{cacheControl.randomDeploymentQueryString}" />
<a:loadScript src="/js/common.js?rand=#
{cacheControl.randomDeploymentQueryString}" />

<a:loadStyle src="resource:////org/richfaces/skin.xcss" />          

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<title>Test2</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Test2</h1>

<h:form style="width:120px; height:120px;" >
<h:commandButton value="Click Me!" onclick="alert('Hello World!');"   
 style="width:100px; height:100px;" />
</h:form>

<rich:panel header="I'm panel header" />
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

css/style.css

```
 div {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

---

When I inspect in chrome the size of h:form or h:commandButton I see only 
( 0 x 0 ) or ( auto x auto ). I can NOT see on page these controls !
But I can see the text "Test2" and the div with red color.
As you can see I set style="width:120px; height:120px;" for h:form but I can not see in browser that control.

I attached a picture with "inspect process" as my proof !
[img]http://up.picr.de/29148479ee.png[/img]

WHY this happened ?
How to solve my problem ?

Can someone help me ?

Please help me.

The same code with richfaces 4 and JSF 2.0 works !

Comment: The picture with inspect process.
http://up.picr.de/29148479ee.png

Comment: Did you have to resize the picture? Try changing the file extension (in the URL) to "jsf", your file is not getting processed by the Faces Servlet.